# Paypal DirectPayment automatically calculate shipping cost?

Tags: paypal

Paypal has this [shipping fee calculator](https://www.paypal.com/sg/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=xpt/Marketing/shipping/EasyCalculateShipAndTax-outside) that is automatically added when the customer reviewed the purchase in Paypal website.

But that calculator only works for payment with Paypal account (`Express Checkout`) and doesn't work for Credit Card (`Direct Payment`) payment.

**Must I write my own** shipping cost calculator in my app?

Sorry for the broad question, but I can't seem to find this info on Google.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shipping fee calculator only applies to PayPal Payments Standard/Website Payments Standard transactions -- it doesn't work for Express Checkout or PayPal Payments Pro/Website Payments Pro ("Direct Payment") transactions.  Unfortunately, this means that you will have to write your own shipping fee calculator.